# Is there a way to lock posts from bad edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

I've just stumbled upon [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/477572/revisions) and oh my look at that revision history. An exception stack changes back and forth between text quote and code block format. A piece of code gets beautified and de-beautified to its original form. All this editing isn't really helpful. And the post is 7 years old. Is there a process for preventing bad edits like that?

Comment: You're looking at an edit war.

Comment: @Laurel: Not really. The edits are months apart and by different users every time, and there are only a couple of edits to the error log.

Comment: Sounds like people think the log is too wide. The leading timestamp could be removed (with a note mentioning it was removed) seeing and it's common to every record.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, there is a process for preventing bad edits.  Edits by users with less than 2k reputation are submitted as suggestions that enter a review queue where reviewers would (hopefully) reject such a bad edit.

But in this case, the post you linked to is a community wiki, which are easier to edit.  Anyone with at least 100 reputation can [edit a community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) without needing to go through the review queue.  This is designed to encourage certain posts to be more collaborative, but it can lead to a few edits like the one you've linked to.